# how to launch an application from a batch file without giving it focus (windows 7)

Tags: batch-file

i have a batch file with a for loop, in which i launch my application repeatedly (the app terminates by itself). i am using:

start /wait /min myapp

in order to have it run minimized and wait for self-termination.
my problem is that the application steals window focus each time it is run.
how can i launch the app without giving it focus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my app is a c# form and the problem was having topmost = true

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Batch/JScript hybrid, so you can use the WScript.Run method.

With the second parameter =7 you got it.

7=(Displays the window as a minimized window. The active window remains active.).
[MSDN Run Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
@if (@X)==(@Y) @goto :Dummy @end/* Batch part
@echo off
setlocal
cscript //nologo //e:jscript "%~f0"
goto :eof

Jscript part begins here */
var sh=new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    sh.Run("cmd /c wait.bat",7,true)
    sh.Run("cmd /c wait.bat",7,true)
```

The `wait.bat`

```
ping -n 5 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: this does not seem to work as intended. i put two calls to my app using the above method (i duplicated the cscript command). after the first call i activate a different window. when the application is launched the second time it steals the focus.

Comment: Even if I start a wait.bat two times and change the focus(manually), I didn't lose the focus. Please post a small sample

Comment: @eyaler: Could it be that the application itself is stealing focus? If so, I doubt you would be able to prevent it using any kind of scripting.

Comment: well my app is a c# form and it seems that the problem was having topmost = true. with this the above method fails. however with topmost = false, it suffices to run minimized and you will not lose focus

Comment: @eyaler: Perhaps it could also work with sh.Run("cmd /c wait.bat",**0**,true), `0` stands for _Hides the window and activates another window_